# librosa y-axis spectrogram does not align properly

Tags: python, matplotlib, librosa, spectrogram, acoustics

How to align axis of spectrogram visualisations in Librosa or Matplotlib ?

Consider this example, [from Librosa's documentation](https://librosa.org/doc/latest/generated/librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff.html):
[image]

as you can see, the rolloff are aligned with the spectrogram.
I can't replicate the figure with my own audio.

The y-axis is never aligned.

Try:

```
sr = 250000
n_fft = 2048
hop_length=256
win_length = 1024
fmin = 220


S, phase = librosa.magphase(librosa.stft(filtered_audio))

sftf_spec = librosa.stft(filtered_audio, n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length)

S = np.abs(sftf_spec)

rolloff = librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(S=S, 
                                           sr=sr, 
                                           n_fft=n_fft, 
                                           hop_length=hop_length, 
                                           win_length = win_length 
                                          )

amplitude_spec = librosa.amplitude_to_db(S, 
                                        
                                     
                                        ref=np.max)

rolloff_min = librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(S=S, sr=sr, roll_percent=0.15)

fig, ax = plt.subplots()

librosa.display.specshow(amplitude_spec,

                         y_axis='log', x_axis='time', ax=ax)

ax.plot(librosa.times_like(rolloff), rolloff[0], label='Roll-off frequency (0.85)')

ax.plot(librosa.times_like(rolloff), rolloff_min[0], color='w',

        label='Roll-off frequency (0.15)')

ax.legend(loc='lower right')

ax.set(title='log Power spectrogram')
```

If you need to replicate, you can try  download the audio wav :

```
https://drive.google.com/file/d/1UCUWAaczzejTN9m_y-usjPbG8__1mWI1/view?usp=sharing
```

```
filtered_audio  = np.array([[  #copy ]])
```

I got this:

[image]

and if I set the rate in specshow, I got this:

```
librosa.display.specshow(amplitude_spec,
                         sr=sr,

                         y_axis='log', x_axis='time', ax=ax)
```

[image]

I want to have the bandwidth following the same scale of the spectrogram they were build from...

Comment: You are not specifying sr to specshow, so likely it is the spectrogram plot that is wrong

Comment: Thanks for the comment, I edited the question. not worked out yet. Somehow the two (spectrogram and timeseries) seems to follow different timesteps. I don't know how to adjust.

Comment: You have not specified hop_length to specplot. In general, all parameters for the spectrogram computation needs to go to specplot for it to be correct

Comment: does not work either. Can you please post a working example ? the array of data is on the link [1]

Comment: Can you provide the audio file in a standard audiio format? Like .wav or similar

Comment: I updated the link with wav file, @JonNordby. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One has to be diligent in passing all the relevant parameters. In your code, both the call to `specshow`, `times_like`, and `spectral_rolloff` were missing key arguments like `sr`, `hop_length` et.c. Without these, both the X and Y axis will typically be off.

When ensuring this, the results look to be correct. See complete code below.

[image]

```py
import librosa
import numpy as np
import pandas

from matplotlib import pyplot as plt
import librosa.display



def plot_spectral(audio, sr, hop_length=256, win_length=1024, n_fft=2048):

    # shared parameters
    spec_params = dict(n_fft=n_fft, hop_length=hop_length, win_length=win_length)

    # compute
    sftf_spec = librosa.stft(audio, **spec_params)
    S = np.abs(sftf_spec)
    amplitude_spec = librosa.amplitude_to_db(S, ref=np.max)

    up = librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(S=S, sr=sr, **spec_params, roll_percent=0.85)
    
    rolloff = pandas.DataFrame({
        'upper': librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(S=S, sr=sr, **spec_params, roll_percent=0.85)[0, :],
        'lower': librosa.feature.spectral_rolloff(S=S, sr=sr, **spec_params, roll_percent=0.15)[0, :],
    })
    rolloff['time'] = librosa.times_like(rolloff['lower'], sr=sr, hop_length=hop_length)

    fig, ax = plt.subplots()

    librosa.display.specshow(amplitude_spec, sr=sr, **spec_params,
                             y_axis='log', x_axis='time', ax=ax, )

    ax.plot(rolloff['time'], rolloff['upper'], color='blue', label='Roll-off frequency (0.85)')

    ax.plot(rolloff['time'], rolloff['lower'], color='white', label='Roll-off frequency (0.15)')

    ax.legend(loc='lower right')

    ax.set(title='log Power spectrogram')

    fig.savefig('spectral-rolloffs.png')


def load_data():
    p = 'test_wav_segment.wav'
    audio, sr = librosa.load(p, sr=None)
    return audio, sr

audio, sr = load_data()


plot_spectral(audio, sr=sr)
```

The use of Pandas is not critical. However it keeps the related data together, and ensures that the times array is equal length to the rolloffs which they are fo.

Comment: Ah thanks @Jon issues was passing the parameter to times_like. I ve seen you've done a thesis in data science and bioacoustics - I am working on a DS thesis that makes use of bioacoustics, but not focused on the performance of model. May I take the chance to contact you to ask a couple of questions ? I don't have background on acoustics properties and would like to double check if some ideas make sense or not, so as to clusterise similar sounds but in absence of ground truth labels.

Comment: Best is to ask questions here on SO, or https://datascience.stackexchange.com/ if they are a bit wider than SO guidelines. Alternatively, ask in the Sound of AI Slack community :)